# How to show that $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ is injection for $x\geq1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know how to start the proof, but I am running cycles and it makes me furious.

An I am also stuck on showing that this function is a surjection.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The derivative is always positive for $x>1$.  What do you mean by "surjection"?  Every function is surjective onto its image.  Here, $x≥1\implies f(x)≥2$ so, for instance, $f(x)=1$ has no solution in the stated domain.

Comment: "I know how to start the proof, but I am running cycles" How did you start the proof?

Comment: @lulu the derivative of function is positive on $x>1$ so it is monotonic increasing so it is injective?

Comment: I presume your "x+1/x" meant $x+\frac1x$ rather than $\frac{x+1}x$. If not, please revert my edit.

Comment: Well, the derivative at $x=1$ is $0$, so you might want to worry about that a little bit.  Not important, though, since $f(x)=2$ only has one solution.  Otherwise $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for $x_1<x_2$ implies that there is a solution to $f'(c)=0$ for some $x_1≤c≤x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y= x+ \dfrac 1 x.$ Then $x^2 -xy + 1 = 0.$ That is a quadratic equation in $x.$ Its solution for $x$ is
$$
x = \frac {y \pm \sqrt{y^2-4}} 2.
$$
If $0<y<2$ then $y^2-4<0$ and there are no real solutions. If $y>2,$ then one of the two solutions is between $0$ and $1$ and the other is $>1.$ To see that, consider what happens if you multiply the two solutions:
$$
\frac{y+\sqrt{y^2-4}} 2 \cdot \frac{y-\sqrt{y^2-4}} 2 = 1.
$$
The two solutions are reciprocals of each other; thus one is $<1$ and the other $>1.$

As far as surjectivity is concerned, notice that $x+\dfrac 1 x=2$ if $x=1,$ and if $x>1$ then
$$
x + \dfrac 1 x > x \to +\infty \text{ as } x\to+\infty,
$$
so the intermediate value theorem tells you that the image of the function is the entire interval $[2,+\infty).$

Comment: Yes I wanted to show that it's a surjection onto [2,+∞), but I forgot to mention it. Is there a way to show it without using the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @MartinBrandys : There is. Namely the first thing I mentioned: solve the quadratic equation. For every $y\in[2,+\infty),$ there is a suitable $x\in[1,+\infty). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x+{1\over x}=y+{1\over y}$ with $x,y\ge1$. Then $x-y={1\over y}-{1\over x}={x-y\over xy}$, hence $(xy-1)(x-y)=0$, which implies $x=y$, since $xy-1=0$ if and only if $x=y=1$ (under the given assumption that $x$ and $y$ are greater than or equal to $1$). So $x+{1\over x}$ is injective for $x\ge1$.

As for surjectivity, the question is unanswerable unless you specify the range (aka codomain).  A function is always surjective onto its *image*, which for $x+{1\over x}$ with domain $x\ge1$ is $[2,\infty)$, as Michael Hardy shows in his answer.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thank you. I tried it this way, but I didn't found the factoring needed.